# WordPress API - how to load a function using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have created a function called `hello_alert` in theme function.php

I want to load this function using ajax when people click on a button.

Instead of creaating a page for ajax request is it possible to load a PHP function directly using ajax API ?

Please give me a commented code to load a php function using Wordpress ajax API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example, [straight from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) (more or less):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );
function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    jQuery('.my_button').click(function(){
        var data = {action: 'my_action'};
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'hello_alert' );
function hello_alert()
{
    echo 'Hello';
    die();
}
```